# LiteDatabase.Execute parameter syntax

Tags: litedb

I could not find any docs on LiteDatabase.Execute method. For example：

```
// UPDATE/SELECT works with @N
db.execute("select value from settings where name = @0", name);
// INSERT fails with @N
db.Execute("insert into settings values { name: @0, value: @1}", name, value);
```